# React Native Notification IOS - APN Configuration

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with the configuration of push notification in IOS. I followed all the steps of the tutorial in the Invertase documentation (https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/messaging/ios-configure-apns), but it didn't work. I read this article, and followed the steps up to the part of generating a development certificate (https://www.codementor.io/@uokesita/react-native-push-notifications-with-firebase-2019-10on0z19t6#generate-a-development-certificate). My JS code is as follows:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
async componentDidMount() {
    await messaging().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    await messaging().requestPermission().then(async granted =>{
        if (granted) {
            console.log('User granted messaging permissions!');
            if(Platform.OS === "ios"){

                console.log("Token: " + await messaging().getToken())
            }
        } else {
            console.log('User declined messaging permissions :(');
        }
    });   
}
  render() {
      return (<AppContainer />)
  }
}
```

Would anyone know to tell me why the notification does not want to appear? And when I request the Token as shown in the code below, the following error also appears:

```
[messaging/unknown] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 1001.)
```